# crontab issue when using exec php script?

Tags: php, ubuntu, cron, cron-task

I am using elementaryOS (base on ubuntu)

When I run commaand line:

```
kn3l@kn3l:/var/www/cronjob$ 
25 15 * * * /var/www/cronjob/helloworld.php > /var/www/cronjob/cron.log
```

and it works for crontab with terminal command line.

BUT When I using PHP with my code like this (test.php):

```
-rwxrwxrwx  1 kn3l kn3l    47 Jun  6 14:59 test.php*
```

test.php

```
<?php
    $output = shell_exec('crontab -l');
    echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

I go to`http://localhost/test.php`

Why I did not see any return like the command line?

Anyone could help me?

Comment: What user is executing the script the php file? Must be some apache, not your user. So it is showing the crontab for apache user.

Comment: `chmod 0777`  on that file

Comment: -rwxrwxrwx  1 kn3l kn3l    47 Jun  6 14:59 test.php*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have in your user crontab the following line:

```
25 15 * * * /var/www/cronjob/helloworld.php > /var/www/cronjob/cron.log
```

in crontab it is necessary to indicate which binary is executing the script. So as [hw indicates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16957876/1983854), you need to replace it to

```
25 15 * * * <path to php> /var/www/cronjob/helloworld.php > /var/www/cronjob/cron.log
```

get this `<path to php>` with `which php`.

Regarding your `test.php` file, take into account that the command `crontab -l` is being executed by the user running the php script. That is, the user running your local server.

#### I did a test:

```
$ ps -ef | grep apac
.../...
www-data  1348  1332  0 09:50 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

so in my case it is www-data the user running apache.

I added your file in `/var/www`:

```
<?php
    $output = shell_exec('crontab -l');
    echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

And nothing appeared while executing it. Why? Because `www-data` has no crontab:

```
$ sudo crontab -l -u www-data
no crontab for www-data
```

I added a line:

```
$ sudo crontab -l -u www-data
* * * * * touch /tmp/tt
```

and now the php page shows:

```
* * * * * touch /tmp/tt
```

#### To sum up

The thing is not that your script is not working properly, is just that is showing an empty content as the crontab for user `www-data` is empty.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
<?
$output = shell_exec('crontab -l');
file_put_contents('/tmp/crontab.txt', $output.'* * * * * NEW_CRON'.PHP_EOL);
echo exec('crontab /tmp/crontab.txt');
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add to first string to test.php

```
#!/usr/bin/php
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to execute the script in this fashion:

```
25 15 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/cronjob/helloworld.php > /var/www/cronjob/cron.log
```

Make sure that `/usr/bin/php` is valid on your system.

Comment: Great. Does this answer your question then? If so, you can accept this answer.