# Set cronjob with php (Raspberry Pi)

Tags: php, linux, cron, raspberry-pi

I want to set a cronjob on the raspberry pi

this is what I want to insert

```
30 16 * * * sudo /home/pi/raspberry-remote/./send 11010 1 1
```

I have tried something like that but it does not work

```
exec("crontab -e 30 16 * * * sudo /home/pi/raspberry-remote/./send 11010 1 1");
```

Comment: Try `shell_exec()` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php Make sure your php is not set in safe-mode.

Comment: i gues its not exec.. its the command itself..

Comment: What's your output? Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16957789/crontab-issue-when-using-exec-php-script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-e` option means an editor opens. That is not what you want.

You need

```
exec('echo "30 16 * * * sudo /home/pi/raspberry-remote/./send 11010 1 1" | crontab -');
```

Comment: hmm did not insert it either

Comment: just the echo inside the php? Did not work for me :/ do I need the exec?

Comment: I was posting the command line command. You need to insert that in the exec(). I've updated to show that.

Comment: Shouldn't it be displayed now if I open it with crontab -e ? There is no cronjob to see

Comment: Yes it should, but beware that the php script might execute as another user (perhaps www-data) and not your user. And only root can see other users crontabs.